# Dimension of polynomially parameterized set of points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, parametric, parametrization

I'm seeking a general method for determining the dimension of a set of points that have polynomial parameterizations.  Any information about what this type of problem would be called would be helpful, any resources, or a clear method for the problem below.  I have very little background in this area of mathematics.

---

Example Problem:

Suppose we have the parameterized functions
\begin{equation} x(a,b,c,d) = ac\end{equation}
\begin{equation} y(a,b,c,d) = bc + ad \end{equation}
\begin{equation} z(a,b,c,d) = bd  \end{equation}

What is the intrinsic dimension of the set \begin{equation} M = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4\}? \end{equation}

Clearly it is not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since points are missing from $M$, such as $(1,0,1)$.  But could it be a volume, surface or just a curve?

---

Possible method of solution:
It was suggested be a friend that maximizing the rank of the Jacobian matrix where the parameterization is smooth gives the dimension of $M$.

The Jacobian is
\begin{equation}
J = \begin{pmatrix} c&0&a&0 \\ d&c&b&a \\ 0&d&0&b \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Since the three rows here are linearly independent in general, one can conclude that $\dim(M) = 3$.  Is this a valid method to determine the dimension of $M$?  If so, I could imagine that this becomes increasingly difficult for larger and more complicated systems.  References on general methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: can you solve for $a,b,c,d$ if $x\neq 0$?

Comment: If $x \neq 0$, then $a$ and $c$ are inversely related.. Not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing from that.  I think what I'm really seeking here is a general method for analyzing such problems and information about what this type of problem would be called (I'm entirely new to this). I sort of just thought this problem up on my own, does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: Ah, then this information should be in your post! It really changes the sort of help one might give you.

Comment: True, fixed it.  Care to provide any resources I could check out if you do not wish to write an answer yourself?  Even just naming this type of problem would be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebraic-geometry perspective on this is that you have a morphism of varieties $X\to Y$ and you're trying to find the equations of (the closure of) the image. The general way to do this is to write $x=ac$, $y=bc+ad$, and $z=bd$ and then eliminate $a,b,c,d$ from these equations using [elimination theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimination_theory).

If you're instead focusing on more of the real-valued aspect of the problem, you can analyze this via semialgebraic geometry. A good starting point to become familiar with this (depending on your level) is [Coste's notes](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/OMIN.pdf).

In this case, there's a no-tech way to approach the problem: the equations are simple enough that we can just solve for $a,b,c,d$ on a suitable open set. When $x\neq 0$, we can set $a=1$, $b=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4xz}}{2x}$, $c=x$, and $d=\frac{y\mp\sqrt{y^2-4xz}}{2}$ which shows that image of our map contains the set $\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3\mid x\neq 0, y^2-4xz>0\}$, which is open in the usual topology. So the dimension of the image is three (we're glossing over a bunch of different ways to define definition and  their possible equivalence here, hope you don't mind).

---

I wrote the above answer before your edit discussing the Jacobian loaded. If you want to use the Jacobian to answer this problem, you may refer to the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48306/jacobian-matrix-rank-and-dimension-of-the-image) which discuss how locally in the standard topology, a map which has Jacobian of rank $k$ in a neighborhood of a point locally looks like a coordinate projection, and the image has dimension $k$. So this is indeed a valid way to solve your problem, as we again speed past the correct notion of dimension to apply here.

Comment: Thanks the references are helpful, and even the "no-tech" solution here is personally interesting to me.  Understanding everything possible about the geometry of $M$ is interesting because the polynomials arise from the product of two (small) Toeplitz matrices.  Thanks a bunch!